# Adding 5 tablerow dynamically

Tags: c#

I am trying to add table rows to a asp.net table from code. I tried the below code. Added the modified code. But getting the error as "Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unexpected error has occurred."

```
 int rowCnt = 5;
            // Current row count.
            int rowCtr;
            // Total number of cells per row (columns).
            int cellCtr;
            // Current cell counter.
            int cellCnt = 4;
    int ctr=0;
         ctr = ctr + 1;
foreach (){
                                        TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
                                        table.Rows.Add(tRow1);

                                        TableCell artifactCell = new TableCell();
                                        artifactCell.ColumnSpan = 4;
                                        tRow.Cells.Add(artifactCell);
                                                                               artifactCell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Artifact " + ctr + " : "));
                                        // Create a Hyperlink Web server control and add it to the cell.
                                        System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink h = new HyperLink();
                                        h.Text = artifact.LookupValue;
                                                                             artifactCell.Controls.Add(h);

                                        TableCell uploadCell = new TableCell();
                                        uploadCell.ColumnSpan = 4;
                                        tRow.Cells.Add(uploadCell);

                                        FileUpload fu = new FileUpload();
                                        fu.ID = "fu_" + BU +"_" + artifact.LookupValue + artifact.LookupId;
                                        fu.AllowMultiple = false;

                                        Button btnUpload = new Button();
                                        btnUpload.ID = "btnUpload_"+ BU + "_" + artifact.LookupValue + artifact.LookupId;
                                        btnUpload.Text = "Upload";
                                        btnUpload.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnUpload_Click);
                                        uploadCell.Controls.Add(fu);
                                        uploadCell.Controls.Add(btnUpload);




                                        for (rowCtr = 1; rowCtr <= rowCnt; rowCtr++)
                                        {
                                            // Create a new row and add it to the table.
                                            TableRow tRow1 = new TableRow();
                                            table.Rows.Add(tRow1);
                                            for (cellCtr = 1; cellCtr <= cellCnt; cellCtr++)
                                            {
                                                // Create a new cell and add it to the row.
                                                TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
                                                tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);

                                                // Create a Hyperlink Web server control and add it to the cell.
                                                System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink hyp = new HyperLink();
                                                hyp.Text = rowCtr.ToString();
                                                hyp.ID = "hyp_" + BU + "_" + artifact.LookupValue + artifact.LookupId;
                                                hyp.NavigateUrl = "http://www.microsoft.com/net";
                                                tCell.Controls.Add(hyp);

                                                HiddenField hid = new HiddenField();                                           
                                                hid.ID = "hdn_" + BU + "_" + artifact.LookupValue + artifact.LookupId;
                                                tCell.Controls.Add(hid);

                                                Label lbll = new Label();
                                                lbll.ID = "lblError_"+ BU + "_" + artifact.LookupValue + artifact.LookupId;
                                                lbll.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;                                            
                                                tCell.Controls.Add(lbll);

                                            }
                                        }
```

This is creating the hyperlink and hidden field. But it is coming in a single row as below, the data are shown in hyperlink

```
1:1 1:2 1:3 1:4 2:1 2:2 2:3 2:4 3:1 3:2 3:3 3:4 4:1 4:2 4:3 4:4 5:1 5:2 5:3 5:4
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
First TR
hyperlink 1
hidden field 1

Second TR
hyperlink2
hidden field 2
```

How to add the table rows dynamically? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code looks as if it contains an error:

```
TableRow tRow1 = new TableRow();
table.Rows.Add(tRow);
```

Change `tRow` to `tRow1` in the loops and it looks like it should work

`tRow` and `tRow1` are not the best variable names. That is most likely the ultimate source of your problems, chose more descriptive names!

Comment: I have updated the full code in the question. but still getting error as Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unexpected error has occurred

Comment: I still see `tRow` in the inner loop which i think might not be correct. I think you should rename `tRow` to something more clear so you can see if you use it where it does not belong

Comment: Updated it to tRow1. But still the same issue

Comment: The issue is in the inner loop

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the typo mentioned by @Adam, changing tRow1 to tRow. Your code seems to work:
The output is like this:

```
1:1 1:2 1:3 1:4
2:1 2:2 2:3 2:4
3:1 3:2 3:3 3:4
4:1 4:2 4:3 4:4
5:1 5:2 5:3 5:4
```

Update:
Changing the inner loop to the static values without the lookup works. Here is the code:

```
for (rowCtr = 1; rowCtr <= rowCnt; rowCtr++)
        {
            // Create a new row and add it to the table.
            TableRow tRow1 = new TableRow();
            table.Rows.Add(tRow1);
            for (cellCtr = 1; cellCtr <= cellCnt; cellCtr++)
            {
                // Create a new cell and add it to the row.
                TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
                tRow1.Cells.Add(tCell);

                // Create a Hyperlink Web server control and add it to the cell.
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink hyp = new HyperLink();
                hyp.Text = rowCtr.ToString();
                hyp.ID = "hyp_"+rowCtr+cellCtr;
                hyp.NavigateUrl = "http://www.microsoft.com/net";
                tCell.Controls.Add(hyp);

                HiddenField hid = new HiddenField();
                hid.ID = "hdn_" + rowCtr + cellCtr;
                tCell.Controls.Add(hid);

                Label lbll = new Label();
                lbll.ID = "lblError_" + rowCtr + cellCtr;
                lbll.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                tCell.Controls.Add(lbll);

            }

        }
```

Comment: I am getting error as Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unexpected error has occurred.

Comment: Again as @Adam replied in the comment the tRow1 in the inner loop is being added empty only and you are adding all the cells to tRow instead.  Change all tRow in cell loop to tRow1.

Comment: As for the exception, you have to double check the values that concatenate in the ID  from BU and lookup and make sure that they are valid. Changing these to normal text value, doesn't produce any exceptions on the page.